# Create iOS7 Icon in Images.xcassets with Xcode5

Tags: ios7, icons, xcode5

How can one create a iOS7 Icon in Images.xcassets with Xcode5? I've searched many places, but i did not find what the required Icon sizes were.

My App is for iOS7+.

**Here is a screenshot:**

[image]

I've added some icons below in the `AppIcon.appiconset` folder in mac. Do I need to add in the xcode side bar? What are the required sizes for the `AppIcon.appiconset` folder?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is very easy & in-fact it is self explanable. You need not even have to think about the name of the icons. The only thing that you need to worry about is the sizes. Here is how to infer the sizes out of that screen.

**BASIC RULE :**  Multiply the `1x` or `2x` shown in the empty box with the `pt` value under it. When there are two boxes like `1x` & `2x` for the same `pt` value, let's say `40pt`, it means you have to provide both the sizes of images. `40x40` & `80x80` .

1. Make sure if your app is Universal or Device specific. Based on that, you need to provide the icons.
2. Point to be noted `Images.xcassets` doesn't sizes your files. It is just a catalog where you add the files of specific sizes.
3. Now let's say you have a `myIcon.png` file of a bigger size (its always better to create your app icon with a size of 1024x1024, if not then at least 512x512).
4. Open the `Images.xcassets` & now read each empty icon elements. There is the size name provided, already.
5. **NOW CONCENTRATE** : If empty dasshed box reads as `2x` & text below reads as `iPhone Spolight - iOS 5,6 Settings - iOS 5-7 29pt`, then it is **actually seeking an image double the size of 29pt, So you need an image size of `58x58`**
6. You just need to re-size your actual image using any editor (previewer is the best editor) & create the specific size. Save it some where & drag upon that specific Box.
7. You are done.

Here is a sample to read it. Hope that makes all your doubt clear going forward.
**You need not have to worry about naming conventions of images when using `Images.xcassets`**

Once you have all your images ready, just drag & drop it into the `Images.xcassets` in Xcode itself. Make sure you are dropping it into `AppIcon` category. Similarly you need to do things for `LaunchImage` as well if you are interested.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining, Am I need to have all size in xcode side bar? After drag, icons are created inside AppIcon.appiconset. So Am I need to keep in two place? Where to specify 1024x1024 Icon?

Comment: You should actually place icons in `Images.xcassets` rather than manually exploring the folder. Both are linked but a better choice is to use the Xcode. So regarding 1024x1024, it is not at all a mandatory icon here but will be required when you submit the app to apple store. When you create iTunes record for your app, it will ask for a file name `largeAppIcon` having size of 1024x1024.
Ok.

Comment: You need to provide images based on your Project `Device` value of `Deployment Info`. I mean if you are targetting for iPhone, just provide images in cat log where it says iPhone. If its universal, you need to provide for iPad as well.

Comment: But to the fact that an app designed for iPhone can be run on iPad in scaled mode, so its better to provide an app icons for iPad as well, so that user should not see a STRETCHED ICON or a MISSING ICON for your app.

Answer (score 0):

### AppICon Sizes - XCAssets -  Xcode 6.4

**iPhone Spotlight
iOS 5-6 - 29pt**

29*29 -1x,
58*58 - 2x,
87*87- 3x

**iPhone Spotlight
iOS 7,8- 40pt**

80*80 - 2x,
120*120 - 3x

**iPhone App
iOS 5,6 - 57pt**

57*57 - 1x,
114*114 - 2x

**iPhone App
iOS 7,8 - 60pt**

120*120 - 1x,
180*180 - 2x

**iPad Settings
iOS 5-8 - 29 pt**

29*29 -1x,
58*58- 2x

**iPad Spotlight
iOS 7,8 - 40pt**

40*40 -1x,
80*80 - 2x

**iPad Spotlight
iOS 5,6 - 50pt**

50*50 -1x,
100*100 - 2x

**iPad App 
iOS 5,6 - 72pt**

72*72 -1x,
144*144 - 2x

**iPad App 
iOS 7,8 - 76pt**

76*76 -1x,
152*152 - 2x