# iPad iOS 7 Icon for a "iPhone only" app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

So here is my situation:

I have an iPhone app that is "iPhone only"  I have separate icons for iOS 6 and iOS 7.  When the app is downloaded on iPad with iOS 7, the iOS 6 is showing.  Which icon size do I need to change in order for the iOS 7 icon to be shown on an iPad? I don't have iPad icon sizes showing because it is a "iPhone only" app and I would not like to use the "Asset catalog" because I am not familiar with it.

[image]

Comment: you are missing  40x40 & 80x80 image  , that required for Icon-Spotlight.

Comment: You say you have separate icons for iOS 6 and iOS 7. But you _don't_ have _any_ icon for iOS 7. The message (third line) is perfectly clear: you need a 120 by 120 image as your main iOS 7 icon.

Comment: "I would not like to use the "Asset catalog" because I am not familiar with it" Getting familiar with it would be good. It's a really great feature.

Comment: For some reason it says there is not a 120x120 icon but there actually is.

Comment: The fact that it thinks there isn't is something you should take seriously. It knows more than you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not really worry about how to pass exact size icons for app (be it any iOS-Device  combination). The `Asset catalog` is your right answer & it takes care of everything you are here confused with. You just need to come out of your comfort zone of passing images manually. Once you use the `Asset catalog`, you will never look back.

Read my answer of understanding `Asset catalog` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292698/1307844).

Now take deep breathe & open `asset catalog`.