# How to understand what xcassets size should I use?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xcasset

I'm trying to make a simple game in swift. But I don't know, what size should I make for my pics. Apple explains sizes of launch screen, icon and such. But, what to do with my background, hero or enemies? Also, should I draw @3x first and then downsize them or how to do it? As a newbe to spritekit and programming in general, I couldn't find that info.

Comment: Its quite simple calculation.. Consider @3x size only for base design. So say your 3x size = 120. 2x will be = 80 and 1x = 40. 2x is 1.5% smaller than 3x.

Comment: are those numbers in pixels or in points? Thank you! That's quite eye-opening for me!. But how to chose that first number? According to a background size?

Comment: Yes.. according to background size..

Comment: Thank you! I think, i'll figure it out now

Comment: Apple Screen Sizes are handled poorly.  Those assets will be the same exact size for the iphone 4,5,6.  To me this does not make sense as I want my game to remain proportional to keep difficulty constant.  What I had to do was pick the closest aspect resolution to 1 I want to support, design the game in an arbitrary size in that aspect ratio, and create methods that will scale your arbitrary Units to pixels.  This will give you a playable area in the center that remains proportional.  You also could supply a hires image and scale it down based on the size in units you want vs dev screen size.

Comment: Most of my concern is background. It's either zoomed or have letterboxes. 
I made one for iPhone 6+ for example. It's 1242x2208 but still it displays with letterboxes. I tried to change scalemodes, not helping. I just can't understand the logic of xcode. What background sizes would you suggest  for at1x, at2x and at3x?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22292698/988169